# Unexpected Issues when Creating New Products in Code with Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to create products programmatically and I am not getting the results I am expecting.  I have truncated core_url_rewrite and rebuilt indexes before running this ( it isn't live ) , and reindexed afterwards.

The unexpected issues:  ( and I am only doing one product to start with in isolation )

1) After saving it , if I edit the product in the admin area then I need to set the tax class before it will save correctly.

Even if I run $targetProduct->setTaxClassId(2); before saving it still asks me to save.

2) The url rewrite adds "-1" ( without the quotes ) to the end of the url path for some reason.  There is only one url rewrite created.

I'm a bit baffled by this , it's not what I am expecting.

```
require_once '../../../app/Mage.php';
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$targetProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
// $productAttributes is an array of attributes
$targetProduct->addData($productAttributes);
$targetProduct->save();
```

EDIT: I fixed #2 by truncating the rewrites table and rebuilding.  there was obviously an entry in there that wasn't showing on the url rewrites list in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    exit;
}
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
try{
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
$product->setSku('99996');
$product->setPrice(99.0000);
$product->setAttributeSetId(4); 
$product->setCategoryIds(array(2));
$product->setType('simple');
$product->setName('Product Name6');
$product->setDescription('The Product Description');
$product->setShortDescription('Brief Description');
$product->setStatus(1);    
$product->setTaxClassId(2);
$product->setWeight(1.0000);                
$product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));

$product->save();

$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
$stockItem->loadByProduct($product->getId());    
if (! $stockItem->getId()) {
    $stockItem->setProductId($product->getId())->setStockId(1);
}
$stockItem->setData('inventory_manage_stock_default', 1);
$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
$stockItem->setData('qty', 10000);

$stockItem->save();

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'DESC');
$collection->setPage(1,1); //set a limit to 1 so the query would be faster
$last_product = $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();

$product_for_tax = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($last_product);
    $product_for_tax->setTaxClassId(2); //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
    $product_for_tax->save();

echo "Product save successfully.";
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Hope now this will save your product with tax class.

Thanks

Comment: No , sorry the tax class is still not set.

Comment: @MartinThompson Answer edited please check.